# Extract first row where value occurs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame where I want to extract the row number where the first value occurs from my filter.

For example:

```
Col1    Col2
  10       A
  22       A
  33       A
  44       B
  55       B
  46       B
  57       B
```

How do I figure out the row number for the first occurrence of the value `B`?

The answer in this case would be 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the result
`which(df$Col2 == "B")[1]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use *match*:

```
match("B", df1$Col2)
# [1] 4
```

Or *dplyr* way (not sure that is the best *dplyr* way):

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(Col2 == "B") %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pull(rn)
# [1] 4
```